# The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, msbuild, electron

I am writing code to load c++ dll from electron. I have installed Visual Studio v141 tools but when running npm install I get the following error:
"The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 b
uild tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\CodeLathe\ElectronPOC\Practice\dll\backup\ElectronCall
ingDll_NaN_CloutDriveTestLib\build\jsToCppBridge.vcxproj]"

I saw all the similar questions in stackoverflow but none of the answers worked for me. The same problem is not reproducible on my colleague's machine

Comment: Could you try setting `npm config set msvs_version 2015` ? This sets the build tools version to lower.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 2):

Could you try setting `npm config set msvs_version 2015` ? 
This sets the build tools version to lower.